# Cómo declarar variable y aumentarla en Angular2

Tags: angular

Estoy usando la variable 'i' en el `<article>` pero aún no existe porque se declara en `el <div de abajo>`

¿Cómo puedo declararla arriba y que aumente en cada pasada del for para saber cuántos articles tengo ?

```
<section class='mycontainer'>

  <article [ngClass]="'myArticle + (i)'">
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div *ngFor="let numberStep of steps; let i = index;" class='circle'></div>
  </article>

</section>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No es posible.

Si quieres saber cuantas `i` tienes... comprueba la longitud de tu array `steps` con su propiedad `length`.

Comment: Gracias, eso he tenido que hacer

Comment: Una duda, se puede hacer un *ngFor si en el steps tengo una variable = 3 y que el ngFor lo haga 3 veces u  ¿ Obligatoriamente tiene que ser un Array ?

Comment: Tiene que ser un array.